# Fix div position after toolbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using a  which displays a title and back button which is always locked at the top of the screen. Also on the page I display a table using  and  . The table contains a 'header' row which I want to also lock (below the toolbar) but I cannot get it to lock. I've used the below without success but if I put the code on a blank html page it works? Would love some help on locking the 'header' row.

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center toolbar-header">Page Title</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<!-- I want to fix this row below the toolbar-->        
<ons-row class="top">
    <ons-col width = "50%">
        <div >Header text</div>           
    </ons-col>
<ons-col width="12.5%">
<div>Item 1</div> 
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col width="12.5%">
<div >Item 2</div>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col width="12.5%">
<div >Item 3</div>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col width="12.5%">
<div >Item 4</div>
    </ons-col>
</ons-row>

<style>
.top{
     position: fixed;
     top:0px;
     left: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The navigation bar has a fixed height, 44px, so you need to set the `top` value to the same height to push it down below the navigation bar:

```
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 44px;
  ...
}
```

Please see this sample:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/ZYPRbj

Comment: Thanks,that is working as desired. However, if I copy the code to my app and view it (iusing phonehap emulator at <http://emulate.phonegap.com/>) it doesn't. If I use the same CSS on a new HTML page it does work (in the emulator). There seems to be a bug in the onsen CSS perhaps?

Comment: @ fraymas It seems to work on my phone so it may be a limitation of the emulator. I've run into another issue with onsenui and the sliding-menu but that's for another day.